# what are the credentials of the JFrog Artifactory docker image's "start account"?

Tags: artifactory

As suggested on https://jfrog.com/open-source/ I pulled the "Latest Artifactory Docker Image", and it's running now, and I can access the web-GUI at port 32782, but what are the "start account" credentials?

Comment: `admin:password`. I assume this is what you mean by "start account"?

Comment: works, thanks.
`admin` sounds good and familiar, but where in the documentation did I miss that password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the admin password while setting up in [the onboarding wizard](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Getting+Started).

If you didn't use the wizard or skipped the password change, the credentials of [the default Admin user](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DefaultAdminUser) are `admin:password`.

Comment: When I launched the Docker image I did not go through that onboarding wizard. Thanks for the hInt!